Maven go-offline with specific/custom plugin
So I have a simple project (use any maven project you have)
And I run the following commands (empty .m2/repository):
mvn dependency:go-offline -B -q
mvn versions:set -DgroupId="your.group.*" -DartifactId="*" -DnewVersion=rc1 versions:commit -o

I get the following error
No plugin found for prefix 'versions' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (~/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

I know because "versions" plugin is not defined in the pom.xml so it is not downloaded by mvn dependency:go-offline -B -q. What is the command to download this plugin without explictly defining it in the pom.xml

Try running mvn versions:help before going offline. You can also use mvn dependency:get with the necessary options, but the former is shorter ;)
